# Problem with ArrayList, Map.Entry<String, ?>) entry

Tags: android

I am getting multiple errors for this line

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, ?>) entry : settings.getAll().entrySet()) list.add(entry.getValue().toString());
```

"not a statement, illegal start of expression, variable declaration not allowed here."

We did this one in class, by did I mean professor told us to write entire code from large display...
Anyone knows how to fix this line?
I am not that good at android studio because of my poor eyesight, so sometimes I make mistakes when writing code from screen :(

**Entire code if needed:**

```
package com.example.student.projekt_7;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    TextView textView;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    int counter;

    private void initializeResources(){
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        settings = getPreferences (MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeResources();
        updateInterface();
    }

    private void updateInterface(){
        ArrayList<String> list = getSettings();
        setListData(list);
        counter = list.size();
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

    }

    private ArrayList<String> getSettings()
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ?>) entry : settings.getAll().entrySet()) list.add(entry.getValue().toString());
            return list;
    }

    private void setListData(ArrayList<String> data)
    {
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                data));
    }

    public void addData (View view)
    {
        addSetting(String.valueOf(++counter));
        updateInterface();
    }

    public void delData (View view)
    {
        clearSettings();
        updateInterface();
    }

    private void addSetting(String key)
    {
        editor.putString(key, getDataTime());
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void clearSettings()
    {

    }

    private String getDateTime()
    {
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTimeMillis);

        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d:%03d",
                year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds,currentTimeMillis%1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a stray `)` in your loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ?>) entry : settings.getAll().entrySet())
                         ^
```

Once you delete that you should be all set.